# How do make sure an event from another thread uses the current instance of my form?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, events

I have a windows form where i subscribe to a few events.

```
FormClosing += save;
EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.BeforeCommit += save;
```

This is a form that is opened in a new thread.

```
void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateItems();
}
```

My save method basically just saves the current state of my form to database.

My form saves fine on FormClosing, but EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.BeforeCommit is from an application running in a different thread, and when that event is fire it is not working correctly. It is almost as if my save method for this event, is getting a blank instance of my form, and overwriting any information populated in the form.

How can i write my code so that EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.BeforeCommit gets the current version of my form to save to the database?

Form Constructor

```
public CheckList(bool canEdit)
{
    this.canEdit = canEdit;
    FormClosing += save;
    FormClosing += updateStatus;
    EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.BeforeCommit += save;
    password.MakeReadOnly();
    SqlCredential sqlCred = new SqlCredential(username, password);
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString, sqlCred);
    connection.Open();
    addHeaders(connection);
    populateItems(connection);
    connection.Close();
    drawFooter();
    isOpen = true;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: `from an application running in a different thread`sounds strange. Is this another application? Also keep in mind, that UI changes only works in UI thread.

Comment: yes, another application

Comment: Then you should show more code. The part of your form with the subscription of the events (constructor) and where `EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.BeforeCommit` comes from.

Comment: My app is a plugin for a commercial application, so i don't have access to the BeforeCommit event directly, but i can subscribe to it. As for the constructor, i'll post it in the OP

Comment: Wire `EncompassApplication.CurrentLoan.BeforeCommit` to another event, then `this.BeginInvoke()` the `updateItems();` method. Very simplified. To test.